# Class-type object not returning values across module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I am writing a simple application in node, but having trouble with referencing objects from different modules.  The object constructor and methods are (I skipped some methods to keep the excerpt short):

```
function Account (name, password) {
  this._name = name;
  this._password = password;
  this._attributes = [];
}
Account.prototype.load = function (id) {
  var self = this;
  self = db.loadObject(id, 'account');  // separate module to save/retrieve data
  this._name = self._name;
  this._password = self._password;
  this._attributes = self._attributes;
  return this;
};
Account.prototype.getAttributes = function () {
  return this._attributes;
}
Account.prototype.addAttributes = function (a) {
  this._attributes.push(a);
};
module.exports = Account;
```

The db module is nothing fancy at this point:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var paths = {
  'account' : './data/accounts/'
};
function loadObject (name, type) {
  var filePath = paths[type] + name + '.json';
  if (!fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
    return false;
  }
  return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8'));
};
function saveObject (object, type) {
  fs.writeFileSync(paths[type] + object.getName() + '.json', JSON.stringify(object),'utf8');
};
exports.loadObject = loadObject;
exports.saveObject = saveObject;
```

The file is saved as:

```
{"_name":"John","_password":"1234","_attributes":[["Jane","sub",[[10,1]]]]}
```

On my caller module I attempt to retrieve the attributes:

```
var Account = require('./account.js');
var account = new Account();
...
account.load(name);
...
var attr = account.getAttributes();
for (var item in attr) {
  console.log(item[0]);
};
...
```

In the code above, the last loop prints undefined objects.  I have checked the files and the information is saved and loaded without any problems.  The array attr is not empty.  If I print it with:
`util.log(typeof attr+': '+attr);`
I get:
`object: Jane,sub,10,1`

Instance issue? Should I rewrite the _attributes to be accessed directly via account.attributes?

Comment: There's nothing that jumps at me as being obviously incorrect. However, if `db.loadObject(id, 'account');` works in some sort of asynchronous way, it could explain the results you are getting. (Database operations are usually asynchronous.) Could you add its code to your question, or if you are using a 3rd-party library provide a link to that library's documentation?

Comment: Is the `load` method doing something async? So the assignments to `this._name` etc all result in undefined because `db.loadObject` returns a promise or something?

Comment: `var self = this;` is confusing. It should just be `var self = db.…`

Comment: @JamesAllardice I thought about your hypothesis but if it were the case then `this._attributes` should be `undefined` and the loop would not even start. (And I believe ragr's mention at the end that "the array attr is not empty" excludes an undefined array.)

Comment: What DB package are you using?

Comment: The db module at the moment is just a simple JSON.parse of readFileSync from a txt file. `return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8'));` I abstracted the db so I can move to something more robust later.  I inserted util.log statements in the db.load and the object is returned properly, including the array.

Comment: @ragr Well, that db module is not async. What's in your json file? That's the only piece of the puzzle that's missing.

Comment: Updated OP with the JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code you currently have for outputting your data:

```
var attr = account.getAttributes();
for (var item in attr) {
  console.log(item[0]);
};
```

What this code does is output to the console the first character of each key in your `_attributes` field. With the data you've shown in your question, what this outputs is `0` because your `_attributes` field has this value: `[["Jane","sub",[[10,1]]]]`. When used in `var item in attr` the `item` variable will get only one value the string `"0"`, and `item[0]` will also evaluate to the string `"0"`. I've actually cut and pasted your code and data into files and ran your code to double check this and this is indeed what I get when I run the code. I don't get undefined values. A more sensible way to get the values out of the array would be:

```
var attr = account.getAttributes();
for (var item in attr) {
  console.log(attr[item]);
}
```

If you want to iterate two levels deep:

```
for (var item in attr) {
    var value = attr[item];
    for (var item2 in value) {
        console.log(value[item2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand how it may seem confusing, but attributes is an array of sub-accounts, which in turn are arrays with their own attributes (including another array of paired values).  In this example there is only one sub-account and one paired set, but the account object could be: `{"_name":"John","_password":"1234","_attributes":[["Jane","sub",[[10,1],[15,3]]],["Dave","sub",[[1,7],[2,5]]]]}`.  The push operation receives the sub-account.  I believe your first paragraph points to what I'm doing wrong, namely referencing the array in an incorrect way. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm going to remove the other stuff.

Comment: I tried accessing attr like you pointed out, and only manage to get the full string `Jane,sub,10,1`.  Trying to print item gives me 0.  attr[item] gives me the full string, and attr[item[0]] the same.  Closer, but for some reason I can't get just Jane.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a method to iterate two levels deep.

Comment: Using the nested loop works now, or instead of the second loop, value[0] for name, value[1] for the type, etc.  It confuses me that I have to assign the array to another variable to be able to access its members, but at least I understand it now.  Thanks again for the help.